# integrating gwt modules/projects into a spring application

Tags: spring, gwt, integrate

The examples of integrating GWT and Spring generally functions as a GWT Project in which various spring services would be integrated into it.  In our project on the other hand we have a spring application and need to integrate a couple of GWT projects/modules into the application.  Does anyone have experience in taking this approach?  I would rather not have to recreated the project as a GWT project and layer in the spring work.  Alternatively is there a way to have the GWT modules/projects exist as separate projects and that can be called by the Spring project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily add GWT capabilities to and existing project in Eclipse: [right-click your project and select Google > Web Toolkit Settings.](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/existingprojects.html) If your project already has a WAR directory it can be reused.

You could easily split project in two parts, but I wouldn't recommend it as you would loose GWT debugging capabilities.

Comment: The project needs to remain a spring application and the GWT projects/modules need to be callable but I do not want to change the overall "flavor" of the project.  Would not the technique you mention convert it to a GWT project?

Comment: I think not. But you can easily give it a try, no?